# Linear independence, when $w\notin\text{span}(u,v)$, $v\notin\text{span}(u)$, and $u\neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let $\underline{u},\:\underline{v},\:\underline{w}$ be vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\underline{w}\notin \text{span}(\underline{u},\underline{v})$, then :     $\underline{v}\notin \text{span}(\underline{u})$ and finally $\underline{u}\neq \underline{0}$. Can these three vectors be linearly dependent?

I think they can't, just comment if you see one (or more) flaws in the logic:
Start by assuming true, then at least one vector must be a linear combination of the other 2, it can't be $\underline{w}$ as it is given in the conditions, so the remaining possibilities are:
$a_1\underline{w}+a_2\underline{v}=\underline{u}$ if $a_1=0$, then $\underline{v}\in \text{span}(\underline{u})$, which is a contradiction.

If $a_2=0$, then $\underline{w}\in \text{span}(\underline{u})$ which is $\in \text{span}(\underline{u},\underline{v})$ which is also a contradiction.
If $a_1\neq 0$ and $a_2 \neq 0$, then $\underline{w}=1/a_1\underline{u}+a_2/a_1\underline{v}$ which means that $\underline{w}\in \text{span}(\underline{u},\underline{v})$ which is again a contradiction.

The last possibility is that $a_1=a_2=0$, but then $\underline{u}=\underline{0}$ which is again a contradiction.

The same series of steps can be carried out with $b_1\underline{w}+b_2\underline{u}=\underline{v}$ getting the same contradictions until the last step which implies $\underline{v}=\underline{0}$, but if that is the case and as assumed the 3 vectors are linearly dependent, then also $\underline{u}$ and $\underline{w}$ must be linearly dependent, which is a contradiction.

Please let me know where the mistakes are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that the three vectors cannot be linearly dependent. Your proof looks correct, but I would argue as follows: Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ be scalars, such that

$$a\underline{u}+b\underline{v}+c\underline{w} = \underline{0}.$$

If $c\neq 0$, then

$$\underline{w} = -\frac{a}{c}\underline{u} - \frac{b}{c}\underline{v},$$

which is a contradiction, so we must have $c=0$. Then
$$a\underline{u}+b\underline{v}=\underline{0}.$$
If $b\neq 0$, then
$$\underline{v} = -\frac{a}{b}\underline{u},$$
again a contradiction, so we must have $b=0$. Then
$$a\underline{u}=\underline{0}.$$
Since $\underline{u}\neq\underline{0}$, we have $a=0$, but then $a=b=c=0$, proving that our three vectors are linearly independent.

Comment: yours is certainly more elegant.